# разбить строку на нужные подстроки, C

Tags: linux, c, строки, strchr

Доброго времени суток.

Есть строка из файла /etc/passwd следующего вида: `"name:x:id:gid:info:root:shell"`

У меня есть структура вида

```
struct user_info {
    char name[256], root[256], shell[256];
    uint16_t id, gid;
}
```

Мне нужно только name, id, gid, root, shell

Этот файл читается в цикле построчно. Я вижу только следующий способ:

```
char sep = ':';
char newline_sep = '\n';
char* pointer_at_sep;
char* buf;

while (fgets(fread_buf, fread_buf_len, f_passwd)) {
    buf = fread_buf;
    /* name */
    pointer_at_sep = strchr(buf, sep);
    *pointer_at_sep = 0;
    strcpy(user_info.name, buf);
    buf = pointer_at_sep + 1;
    *pointer_at_sep = 0x30; // что бы очистить fread_buf одним memset перед следующим fgets

    /* skip x */
    pointer_at_sep = strchr(buf, sep);
    buf = pointer_at_sep + 1;

    /* get id */
    pointer_at_sep = strchr(buf, sep);
    *pointer_at_sep = 0;
    user_info.id = atoi(buf);
    buf = pointer_at_sep + 1;
    *pointer_at_sep = 0x30;

    /* get gid */
    pointer_at_sep = strchr(buf, sep);
    *pointer_at_sep = 0;
    user_info.gid = atoi(buf);
    buf = pointer_at_sep + 1;
    *pointer_at_sep = 0x30;

    /* skip info */
    pointer_at_sep = strchr(buf, sep);
    buf = pointer_at_sep + 1;

    /* get root */
    pointer_at_sep = strchr(buf, sep);
    *pointer_at_sep = 0;
    strcpy(user_info.root, buf);
    buf = pointer_at_sep + 1;
    *pointer_at_sep = 0x30;

    /* get shell */
    pointer_at_sep = strchr(buf, newline_sep);
    *pointer_at_sep = 0;
    strcpy(user_info.shell, buf);

    memset(fread_buf, 0, pointer_at_sep - fread_buf);
}
```

Про strtok: иногда бывает в строке так: `"name::id:gid::root:shell"`, по этой причине strchr. По мне, с выглядит проще, с ним можно пропустить конкретный участок (как ckip x, skip info).

Есть ли более изящный и короткий способ в теле цикла вытащить нужные строки в C? Возможно я что-то упускаю. Благодарю за внимание.

Answer (score 0):

Наверное (это я про размер, изящность и т.п. критерии).

Можно написать функцию, которая вызывается в цикле и возвращает очередное поле из строки. При этом нужно самому подсчитывать номера полей и решать, как обрабатывать это поле в зависимости от его номера.

Например, вот такой код просто печатает поля с их номерами:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *
get_field (const char *f, char sep, int *pl)
{
  if (!f || !f[*pl])
    return 0;
  f += *pl;
  if (*f == sep)
    f++;
  int l = 0;
  while (f[l] && f[l] != sep)
    l++;

  *pl = l;
  return (char *)f;
}

  

void
print_fields (const char *str, char sep)
{
  const char *f = str;
  int f_len = 0,
    i = 0;

  // first empty field -- text like ":qwe:123::456"
  // must be processing separatly
  if (*f == sep) 
    printf("field_%d = <>\n", ++i);
  
  while ((f = get_field(f, sep, &f_len))) {
    char *p = strndup(f, f_len);
    printf("field_%d = <%s>\n", ++i, p);
    free(p);
  }
  
}


int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{

  for (int i = 1; av[i]; i++)
    print_fields(av[i], ':'), puts("");
  
  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Компилируем и запускаем:

```
avp@avp-xubu2:~/hashcode$ gcc t.c && ./a.out qq qq:uuu qq::uuu :qq:uu:  "::123:a:bbb::c: :: " 
field_1 = <qq>

field_1 = <qq>
field_2 = <uuu>

field_1 = <qq>
field_2 = <>
field_3 = <uuu>

field_1 = <>
field_2 = <qq>
field_3 = <uu>
field_4 = <>

field_1 = <>
field_2 = <>
field_3 = <123>
field_4 = <a>
field_5 = <bbb>
field_6 = <>
field_7 = <c>
field_8 = < >
field_9 = <>
field_10 = < >

End
avp@avp-xubu2:~/hashcode$
```